# Python fails writing to a file citing 'FileNotFoundError'

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

Why does the following interaction fail? (python 3.6.1)

```
>>> with open('an_image.png', 'rb') as f, open('~/Desktop/an_image.png', 'wb') as g:  
...     g.write(f.read())  
...  
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in
<module> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'~/Desktop/an_image.png'  
>>>
```

Isn't the 'w' mode supposed to create the file if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Hm, the trace back does not match the code snippet (hint rei_G_01.png does not match an_image.png - sometimes when editing for terseness I fix my code ... or add mistakes ;-) But I guess in this case, the tilde may be unexpanded, and thus the folder where to place the file is not found, right?

Comment: @Dilettant: No this is my bad. I changed the file names manually when writing this post, but didn't do a thorough job...

Comment: No problem, check the tilde expansion ... maybe go for something like `os.path.expanduser(path)`

Comment: The `~` is a shell expansion character, not used by Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Dilettant said, remove the `~`. You can specify the absolute path manually, or use `os.path.expanduser`:

```
import os

desktop_img = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/an_image.png')
# desktop_img will now be /home/username/Desktop/an_image.png

with open('an_image.png', 'rb') as f, open(desktop_img, 'wb') as g:  
    g.write(f.read())
```